# Primefaces Editor and ajax submission on blur

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a Primefaces editor on my page and I want to submit the content to the server when the user focuses on a different component on the page.

```
<p:editor value="#{}">
    <p:ajax />
</p:editor>
```

This works find for example with `p:inputText`, but with the editor I get this error:

```
Unable to attach <p:ajax> to non-ClientBehaviorHolder parent
```

I also tried adding the `onchange` attribute to the `p:editor` and calling a `remoteCommand` to submit the content, like this:

```
<p:editor widgetVar="documentation" onchange="submitDocumentation" />
<p:remoteCommand name="submitDocumentation" process="@parent" update="@none" />
```

That works, but on every single keystroke.  I only want to submit the content of the editor when the focus is lost.

Is it possible to use Ajax to submit the content of a Primefaces Editor when focus is lost?

Using Tomcat 7, Mojarra and Primefaces 4.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in the next way.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   //documentation is the editor widgetVar
   PF('documentation').jq.find("iframe").contents().find('body').blur(function(){
      submitDocumentation();//remoteCommand
   });
});
```