# Primefaces Editor Blur Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I use JSF Mojarra 2.2.8 with PrimeFaces 5.1. For text input I use a primefaces editor and I want to upload the inserted text automatically with ajax.

The editor supports only an onchange event.
Any suggestions how I can get a blur event working for an editor to reduce the request number?
I tried this solution ([Primefaces Editor and ajax submission on blur](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20619322/primefaces-editor-and-ajax-submission-on-blur)), but the event was never fired.
Thanks.

```js
<h:form>
      <p:editor widgetVar="documentation" onchange="submitDocumentation" />
      <p:remoteCommand name="submitDocumentation" process="@parent"
        update="@none" />
        <p:inputText></p:inputText>
    </h:form>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        //documentation is the editor widgetVar
        PF('documentation').jq.find("iframe").contents().find('body').blur(function(){
         alert("test");
           submitDocumentation();//remoteCommand
        });
     });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer by myself:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  PF('inputOverview').jq.find("iframe").contents().find('body').focusout(function() {
    alert('a');
    saveOverview();
  });
});
```